# Spring MVC4 + AngularJS - Resolve css/js and JSP

Tags: angularjs, spring

I'm trying to integrate Spring MVC4 + Angular JS but i have some problems to load template from AngularJS side. On the net there are a lot of resources, but IMHO a bit confused.

Right now i've setup a simple controller that render a page under `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`. This works fine but when in this page i try to load js (angular library) i got error (resource unavailable).

I've added this to my `view.jsp` and resource is not loaded:

```
<script src="resources/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
```

I'm my `dispatcher-servlet.xml` i have the follow configuration:

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<bean id="jspViewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView"/>
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

To load correctly my angular library, i have to use `c tag` library, **why ?**

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/angular/angular.js" />"></script>
```

Next on it, i have created a template under `webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/templates/main.jsp` and i'm trying to load it using `$routeProvider` (i've tried to load `main.jsp` too, but the error is the same - **resource not found**)

```
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'templates/main'
            });
    });
```

My answer is:

1. How i can load "library" without using c taglib ?
2. What i have to add to my configuration to load templates from AngularJs ? (using templateUrl) ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is probably du to some path problems. We need to know the URL of each resources to check that for you Try using the base tag on your index.jsp. By the way, are you doing a Single Page application ? If so there is probably no benefits of using jsp files.

Comment: Yes, i'm trying to develop a single page application. I've used jspViewResolver just to have a template engine. There is a better way to handle this? (without using JSP ?)

Comment: If you're using a REST API with Spring's controller. A simple HTML/JS/CSS files registered as resource will do perfectly the job.

Comment: Great, for sure i will use a REST API (i dont want in my server code ModelAndView and so on). Can you please provide me a little example how to modify my configuration to handle this? Many thanks!

Comment: I split my project into 2 projects : one backend with REST API and the front . Just enable context:annotation-config and use annotation for mapping and so on. The front is just an index page with all JS to load and the templates. In my project. I use jackson to handle json serialization, just check their site about how configuring Spring with him, it's really easy. My configuration in my xcurrent project is more complicated ecause i have jax-rs/CXF with it. Basically you just declare the seerializer jackson and perform all mapping with annotation, no more configuration.